# How to write a variable into a file made in python 3.7

Tags: python

I'm saving a file of scores from python but it comes up with an error
when I'm trying to save a variable that is a user created and one that changes throughout the program

i tried to change it but it dosent work

```py
def CreateFile():
   global CreateFile
   CreateFile = open("Score.txt", "w")
   CreateFile.write(p1,"Had",p1sc," points") 
   CreateFile.write(p2,"Had",p2sc," points")
   if p1sc > p2sc:
      CreateFile.write(p1," won with",p1sc," points")
      CreateFile.write(p2," lost with",p2sc," points")
   elif p2sc > p1sc:
      CreateFile.write(p2," won with",p2sc," points")
      CreateFile.write(p1," lost with",p1sc," points")

print("The score's have been saved in a file called 'Score.txt' ")
CreateFile()
```

p1 and p2 are input variables
p1sc and p2sc are variables that can change

the error message i get is:

```py
  Exception has occurred: TypeError
write() takes exactly one argument (4 given)
  File "/Users/joshua/Desktop/aaHomeProjects/Programming/PythonProjects/DiceGame2ElecticBoogaloo.py", line 248, in CreateFile
    CreateFile.write(p1,"Had",p1sc," points")
  File "/Users/joshua/Desktop/aaHomeProjects/Programming/PythonProjects/DiceGame2ElecticBoogaloo.py", line 261, in <module>
    CreateFile()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

Comment: During open you're using x-mode. `'x': open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists` You are probably running the script again without deleting the file. try `w` mode instead.

Comment: finomis, you have decimated my feelings

Comment: ... you've somehow managed to write a function that literally deletes itself when called; I didn't know that was possible. :D (Try to call this function twice - you'll notice that by declaring a global variable named after itself, it overwrites itself and can't be called a second time.)

Comment: Christoph Burschka thank you I didn't notice this mistake

Comment: @ChristophBurschka, wow, that's pretty cool! One can also write a function that commits suicide after having been called: `def Func(): global Func del Func`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error you're getting is due to using `file.write()` incorrectly. Unlike `print()`, which takes an arbitrary number of positional arguments and automatically concatenates them with spaces, `file.write()` requires a single string argument.

In your case, you should replace all the calls like `write(p1,"Had",p1sc," points")` with a format string like `write(f"{p1} Had {p1sc} points")` (Python 3.6+) or `write("{p1} Had {p1sc} points".format(p1=p1, p1sc=p1sc))` (Python 3.5 and older).

Aside from that:

1. see the comment on global names. As a general rule, avoid declaring global variables if at all possible (for example, you should pass the variables p1, p1sc, p2, p2sc as arguments), and be aware that functions and variables share the same namespace. If you assign a value to `CreateFile`, you'll overwrite the `CreateFile()` function and no longer be able to call `CreateFile()` in the same scope.
2. It is also common practice in Python to use a `with` block when opening files, which implicitly closes them after you're done:

--

```
def CreateFile(p1, p1sc, p2, p2sc):
   with open("Score.txt", "w") as file:
       file.write(f"{p1} Had {p1sc} points")
       # etc
```